# Yii 1.1 How to get raw query from queryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii1.x

I have YII PHP code below:

```
   $query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('id,email')
        ->from('users')
        ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>2))
        ->getText();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($query); echo "</pre>"; exit;
```

Output:

```
SELECT `id`, `email`
FROM `users`
WHERE id=:id
```

Expected Result:

```
SELECT `id`, `email`
FROM `users`
WHERE id=2
```

Please help

Comment: If just to see how it looks, you can turn on logging and write your own logger that takes params and replaces it in query

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this way:

```
$query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('id,email')
        ->from('users')
        ->where('id=:id', array(':id'=>2))
        ->getText();
var_dump($query->params);
var_dump($query->text);
```

> If there are any parameters to be bound to the query, they can be retrieved via the CDbCommand::params property.

Check please the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder)

Comment: I am getting  the null value `/var/www/html/test/protected/controllers/TestController.php:7387:null` and  
`/var/www/html/test/protected/controllers/TestController.php:7388:null`